# How to make an activity always run in background

Tags: android

I am making an application in which i am using broadcast reciever to call a service. The problem is that I have to open the application to make the service work. I want that just install application and it will run the service automatically.

In the main activity I have used Intent filter and I have made a class for brodcast reciever and called onRecieve method

Comment: If you want something to run always on background, why you need an activity? You can use a service instead.

Comment: ... and start that service in a `BroadcastReceiver` that is started with BOOT_COMPLETED or USER_PRESENT event. There is a slight chance that your service is stopped on low memory. In order to prevent this start the service in foreground.

Comment: The fact that you have to open an activity before the app is enabled [is a feature](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols). You have to have something that can be started so the app is enabled after installation.

Comment: can you show me an example how to do so??

Comment: @Karma5 what you really want?

Comment: @Karma5 If your problem was solved using the answer provided below then please accept them or provide your own answer and then accept it to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run something in background it should be a **Service**. It was designed specifically for this purpose. The sole purpose of an **Activity** is **user interaction**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startforeground()` method in your service to avoid getting it killed.